# Trying to run remote task in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to kick off a scheduled task on a remote server using the wrapper from the site http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/. Apparently the FindTask method is not working and is returning a null reference. The task I am trying to find is located at c:\Windows\System32\Tasks\Titanium on the remote server. I have taken out the parameters from the tasksrvc creation to protect the information. I have been using breakpoints when debugging and I've isolated the error to the FindTask method. Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;

using (TaskService tasksrvc = new TaskService(@"source server", username, domain, password, true))
            {

                Task task = tasksrvc.FindTask(taskname);
                task.Run();
            }
```

Here is the error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.